# ruby on rails change default column on Model.find()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, find

I have a table with posts and its schema looks like

```
id | post_id | title | body | etc...
```

Now, when i use

`Post.find(params[:id])`

it **searches** the **id column** which is not what i want since i **display the unique** `post_id` instead of the `id`...

so how can i make sure the `Post.find()` will search in `post_id` column **instead**?

Comment: what is `bucket_id`?  do you mean `post_id`?

Comment: I hope this is a legacy database, because otherwise it seems weird that `posts.id` is not the ID of the Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.find_by_post_id(params[:id]
```

Also, Model.find is tied to your primary key.
If you can use post_id as the primary_key then you can just tell rails that post_id is it like so:

```
self.primary_key = :post_id
```

Comment: You can use this same convention for any field

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `post_id` instead `bucket_id` (which doesn't fit with the rest of your description) use:

```
Post.where( "post_id = #{params[:id]}").first
```

Note: `.first` since you mentioned it's unique.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want to rewrite the ActiveRecord .find method, just use

```
Post.where(:post_id => id)
```